# SQL Server 2012 SSRS Over AlwaysOn Availability Group

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am setting up SQL BCDR for my project using SQL Server 2012 Availability group. I could successfully implement it for my database. But I have SSRS, which I want to include in the Availability group.

What is the best approach for this. Ideally, I would want my client to connect to the reporting server using the listener name or a common static name, so that during fail-over the client doesn't need to change anything.

Any good read in terms of configuring SSRS with AlwaysOn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common situation but certainly achievable with the built scalability feature in SQL Server 2012 (AlwaysOn Availability Groups). There are few limitations and things to consider when planning on using SSRS with AlwaysOn Availability Groups. Please refer to this link for further detail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882437.aspx